# Concatenate two lists using condition

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I need to concatenate lists `A` and `B` using condition that two lists transform to list `C`, with the same length, but each `i` element doesn't change position and list is sorted. Else return empty list:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

concatenated to: `C = ['a', 'b', 'z']`.

or

```
A = ['8', '2', '3']
B = ['1', '2', '0']
```

concatenated to: `C = ['1', '2', '3']`.

I absolutely have no idea how I can start solve my problem. Which algorithm I have to use?

**UPD:**

Another examples:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = ['x', 'x', 'x']
```

result is: `['a', 'b', 'x']`

```
A = ['b', 'a']
B = ['x', 'c']
```

result must be: `['b', 'c']`.

And result of concatenation of these two lists is an empty list:

```
A = ['e','a'], 
B = ['f','b']
```

Comment: I don't think you mean *concatenation*. From your examples, you want some kind of merging. I'm also entirely confused by what are the rules you're supposed to be merging on,  based on your examples. You mention 'sorting' but I have no idea why 'a,b,c' is not already 'sorted' enough

Comment: Hi, I updated my examples. Yes, `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `['x', 'y', 'z']` is sorted already, but I need to create new one, also sorted, with the same length, but using element from two lists.

Comment: What should `['e','a'], ['f','b']` give?

Comment: @hege_hegedus yeah, an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to switch the last two elements in each list? If so, this is a simple way that lets you see what is going on.

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['x', 'x', 'x']

lst3 = lst1
lst3[len(lst2)-1] = lst2[len(lst2)-1]

lst3
Out: ['a', 'b', 'x']
```

Else, explain the logic behind what you are trying to do a little more.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a greedy algorithm, iterate over both list and take the minimum value that is greater from the previous item you had taken.

```
prev = None
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = ['x', 'x', 'x']
n = len(A)
result = []
for i in range(n):
    mn, mx = A[i],B[i]
    if mx<mn:
       mn,mx = mx,mn
    if prev == None or mn >= prev:
       prev = mn
       result.append(prev)
    elif mx >= prev:
       prev = mx
       result.append(prev)
    else:
       print "can't be done"
       break
if len(result) == n:
    print result
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, but I've got `['a', 'b', 'c' ]`, when the expected output is `['a', 'b', 'x' ]`

Comment: I am pretty sure that the expected output should be `['a', 'b', 'c' ]` because if it isn't there is no easy way to do what you want in other words no greedy algorithm will solve this for you.